# C: No such file or directory

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor, mode

when I hard code `chemin` in `open(chemin, O_RDONLY)` to a file name, the program works, but when I leave if to `open(chemin, O_RDONLY)` I get `No such file or directory`.

Why isn't `chemin` in type_fichier used?

When i use `printf("%s", chemin)` in `type_fichier` I get `'`

```
int type_fichier(char * chemin) {
  int fp;
  if ((fp = open(chemin, O_RDONLY)) == -1) { perror(""); exit(0); }

  struct stat fileStat;
  if(fstat(fp, &fileStat) < 0)
    return 1;

  switch(fileStat.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
    case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
    case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
    case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
    case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
    case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
    case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
    case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
    default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char fn = "file";
  type_fichier(&fn);
}
```

Comment: Do you listen to your compiler's warnings at all? Something about *initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast* should give you a mighty clue.

Comment: Your code is not even compilable by any pedantic C compiler. And that is exactly what you should do with any C compiler: run it in the most pedantic mode possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is here, you are allocating only 1 character for `fn`:

```
char fn = "file";
type_fichier(&fn);
```

You probably want:

```
const char *fn = "file";
type_fichier(fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `char` variable for storing string literal instead of char array or an equivalent one.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char fn[] = "file";
  type_fichier(fn);
}
```

there you go....